# Updating useState array with promise chaining with Axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, promise

I'm currently update useState array with sequential call to backend API with promise chaining using Axios.

I want to sequentially call 3 different API endpoints and gradually add elements so the total number of items in the array is 20.

My code currently looks something like this:

```
const [data, setData] = useState([])

function getData() {
  const target = 'http://localhost:5000/api/backend/target/'

  axios.get(target + 'one')
  .then(res => {
    setData([...data, ...res.data].slice(0, 20))
  })
  .then(axios.get(target + 'two'))
  .then(res => {
    if (data.length < 20) {
      setData([...data, ...res.data].slice(0, 20))
    }
  })
  .then(axios.get(target + 'three'))
  .then(res => {
    if (data.length < 20) {
      setData([...data, ...res.data].slice(0, 20))
    }
  })
}

useEffect(() => {
  getData()
}, [])
```

This *works* (not really) if the first endpoint returns more than 20 entries, but doesn't work if the first endpoint returns less than 20 entries, which means that the call to other two endpoints are simply not working.

Comment: Could you do a quick check on `length()` and (if the number of items > 20)  THEN slice?

Comment: @Zak I just tried that but still isn't working. I think there must be a problem with the method I'm using to call the endpoints sequentially - looks like it just isn't working as intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems. First there's this:

```
.then(axios.get(target + 'two'))
```

This code *immediately* calls `axios.get(target + 'two')`, and passes its result into `.then`. So you're actually doing all the `.get`s right away, and since `.then` is expecting a function not a promise, it won't run anything later.

Instead, you need to pass a function into `.then`, which tells it what you want to eventually do, as in:

```
.then(() => axios.get(target + 'two'))
```

Secondly, there's this:

```
if (data.length < 20) {
  setData([...data, ...res.data].slice(0, 20))
}
```

The `data` variable here is the empty array from the first render of the component. Any changes you've made to the state since then are not in here, so data.length will always be less than 20, and you'll always be copying an empty array.

Instead, you need to use the function version of setState to make sure you have the latest version of the state:

```
setData(prev => {
  if (prev.length < 20) {
    return [...prev, ...res.data].slice(0, 20);
  } else {
    return prev;
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation - I was able to understand the problem right away! After some research, I ended up using `Promise.all` to resolve the issue, but I appreciate your answer regardless. Thanks!